# a) Is f continuous if $\lim_{h\to0}[f[(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0$? b) is $f$ continuous if $\lim_{h\to0}[f[(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)]=0$?

Tags: functions, continuity

Additional notes:
$f:R\to R$, functions are true for every $x$ in $R$

My Work:
$$\lim_{h\to0}[f[(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0$$
a) I claimed that this function is not continuous because the function is not defined for $f(x)$. It shows that the overall function has a left handed limit and a right handed limit, but does not define $f(x)$ to a certain point. A counter example would be that $f(x)=x$ except when $x=0$. When $x=0$, $f(x)=5$. I believe that this function follows all of the parameters of the problem, but is not a continuous function.
$$\lim_{h\to0}[f[(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)]=0$$
b) For this problem, $f(x)$ has a little bit more definition than in the previous problem. I believe that this is enough to prove that the function will be continuous based on my findings in Part A.

I post this question so that I can get some clarification (and possibly correction) to my logic. This problem is the first problem regarding continuity in my Math analysis course, and I'm trying to confirm that my thinking is parallel to the level of thinking required for the course.
Any tips, hints, or corrections are welcome!

Comment: Re b), consider $f(t)=-1$ if $t<0$, $f(t)=1$ if $t>0$ and $f(0)=0$, at $x=0$.

Comment: As stated, your reasoning is good. Any $f$ constant everywhere except at $x$ will work out fine. This makes me think that the question might really be asking if there is continuity when $\lim_{h \to 0} h^{-1} [f(x+h)-f(x-g)] = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Your example is good

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\ne0 \\ 5,&x=0  \end{cases}$$

b) A modified step function with a defined value of the average of the two values at the "step" will satisfy the condition without being continuous

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<0 \\1,&x>1 \\\tfrac{1}{2},&x=0  \end{cases}$$

This is not continuous at $x=0$, because neither of the one-sided limits equals the function value at $x=0$. It is easily verified that

$$\lim_{h\to0}[f[(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)]=\begin{cases}
0+0-2\cdot0=0,&x<0 \\ 
1+1-2\cdot1=0,&x>0 \\ 
1+0-2\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}=0,&x=0
\end{cases}$$
So this limit is zero everywhere.

---

Note that the similar limits (but divide by $h$ or $h^2$) are:

1. Central difference for the derivative when it exists:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\left[\frac{f[(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h}\right]$$

2. The second derivative when it exists:

$$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\left[\frac{f[(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2}\right]$$